# How to load items from an FireStoreRecyclerAdapter inside of items (comments -> subcomments)

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

**Explanation** I am working on a social media app, where a user can post posts. When a user clicks on the "comments" button of that post he will be directed to an activity called "onlickPost" where all the data gets transfered fromn the post to display it larger and show the post´s comment below in a Recyclerview to be specific in a FireStoreRecyclerAdapter. Every comment has also a recyclerview attached to it and in this recyclerview the subcomments to that specific comment should be shown.

Here all 3 layouts so you get a better idea:

[image: 1]
[image: 3]
[image: 2]

1 is the layout for the clickpostactivity posting of comments and subcomments is handled here
(in this recyclerview all comments get loaded)

2 is the layout for a comment (in this recyclerview all subcomments should get loaded)

3 is the layout for the subcomment (all of these items shold display below 2)

**What I have tried**
**1.** I tried to do this subcommentsloading inside the commentsadapter class with this code:

```
        Query query = subCommentsRef.orderBy("time",Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<SubComments> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<SubComments>().setQuery(query, SubComments.class).build();
        adapter = new SubCommentsAdapter(options);
        holder.subcommentsList.setHasFixedSize( true);
        holder.subcommentsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager( getClass() ) );
        holder.subcommentsList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem here is I cannot get the context for the LinearLayoutManager and if try to use the "clickPostActivity.class" it still does not work

**2.** I tried to do the loading inside the clickPostActivity class but the problem here is how am I supposed to pass every single recyclerview of the item of a certain position ?

**3.** I tried to create a method inside the CommentsAdapter.class and call it into the clickPostActivity class but still the recyclerview problem of every item remains

**CODE** I am going to provide the code to the CommentsAdapter class with the relevant parts

```
public class CommentsAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Comments, CommentsAdapter.CommentsHolder> {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private onConfirmCommentsClickListener listener;
    private onCommentsLikeClickListener listener2;
    private onSubCommentsPostClickListener listener3;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference subCommentsRef = db.collection( "subComments");
    private SubCommentsAdapter adapter;

    public CommentsAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Comments> options) {
        super( options );
    }

    public void deleteItem(int position) {
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot( position ).getReference().delete();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CommentsHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Comments model) {
        String commentID = model.getCommentID();
        holder.commentDescriptionTextView.setText( model.getDescription() );
        holder.commentPostTimeTextView.setText( "uploaded " + timeAgo );
        holder.commentUserUIDTextView.setText( model.getUid() );
        holder.commentUsernameTextView.setText( model.getUsername() );
        holder.commentPostTypeTextView.setText( String.valueOf( model.getCommentType() ) );
        holder.commentLikesButton.setText( "Likes: " + model.getLikes() );
        if (model.profileImage == null) {

        } else {
            Picasso.get().load( model.getProfileImage() ).placeholder( R.drawable.ic_action_profile ).into( holder.commentProfilePicture );
        }

        if (holder.commentPostTypeTextView.getText().equals( "0" )) {
            holder.commentPictureImageView.setImageDrawable( null );
            holder.commentPictureImageView.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        } else if (holder.commentPostTypeTextView.getText().equals( "1" )) {
            Picasso.get().load( model.getPicture() ).into( holder.commentPictureImageView );
        }

        //Likes
        if (model.getHasLiked().contains( mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() )) {
            holder.commentLikesButtonHeart.setColorFilter( Color.rgb( 255, 0, 0 ) );
        } else {
            holder.commentLikesButtonHeart.setColorFilter( Color.rgb( 255, 255, 255 ) );
        }

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CommentsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.comments_layout, parent, false );
        return new CommentsHolder( v );
    }

    class CommentsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CircleImageView commentProfilePicture;
        ImageButton commentOptions, commentLikesButtonHeart;
        TextView commentUserUIDTextView, commentPostTypeTextView, commentPostTimeTextView, commentDescriptionTextView, commentSubcommentTextView, commentUsernameTextView;
        ImageView commentPictureImageView;
        Button commentLikesButton, commentSubcommentPostButton, commentDeleteConfirmButton, commentDeleteCancelButton;
        RecyclerView subcommentsList;
        LinearLayout commentDeleteView;

        public CommentsHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super( itemView );
            commentProfilePicture = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_profileImage );
            commentUsernameTextView = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_userName );
            commentOptions = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_options );
            commentLikesButtonHeart = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_likes_heart );
            commentUserUIDTextView = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_userUID );
            commentPostTypeTextView = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_postType );
            commentPostTimeTextView = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_uploadTime );
            commentDescriptionTextView = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_description );
            commentSubcommentTextView = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_subcomment_text );
            commentPictureImageView = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_image );
            commentLikesButton = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_likes );
            commentSubcommentPostButton = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_subcomment_post );
            commentDeleteConfirmButton = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_delete_confirm );
            commentDeleteCancelButton = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_delete_cancel );
            subcommentsList = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comments_subcommentList );
            commentDeleteView = itemView.findViewById( R.id.comment_delete );
            commentDeleteView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
            commentUserUIDTextView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
            commentPostTypeTextView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
            commentOptions.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    commentDeleteView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                }
            } );
            commentDeleteCancelButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    commentDeleteView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
                }
            } );
            commentDeleteConfirmButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                        listener.onConfirmCommentsClick( getSnapshots().getSnapshot( position ), position );
                    }
                    commentDeleteView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
                }
            } );

            commentLikesButtonHeart.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener2 != null) {
                        commentLikesButtonHeart.setColorFilter( Color.rgb( 255, 0, 0 ) );
                        listener2.onLikeClick( getSnapshots().getSnapshot( position ), position );
                    }
                }
            } );

            commentSubcommentPostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(commentSubcommentTextView.getText())) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener2 != null) {
                            String descritpion = commentSubcommentTextView.getText().toString();
                            listener3.onSubCommentsPostClick( getSnapshots().getSnapshot( position ), position, descritpion);
                        }
                    } else {
                        commentSubcommentTextView.setText( "You need to type something in first");
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    }

    public interface onConfirmCommentsClickListener {
        void onConfirmCommentsClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }

    public void setOnConfirmCommentsClickListener(CommentsAdapter.onConfirmCommentsClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface onCommentsLikeClickListener {
        void onLikeClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }

    public void setOnCommentsLikeClickListener(onCommentsLikeClickListener listener) {
        this.listener2 = listener;
    }

    public interface onSubCommentsPostClickListener {
        void onSubCommentsPostClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position, String description);
    }

    public void setOnSubCommentsPostClickListener(onSubCommentsPostClickListener listener){
        this.listener3 = listener;
    }

}
```

and here the clickPostacitvity relevant parts:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_click_post );
        toolbarBack = findViewById( R.id.toolbar_action_2);
        commentBarText = findViewById(R.id.commentbar_text);
        //KeyBoard Force
        commentBarText.requestFocus();
        commentBarText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.showSoftInput(commentBarText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }
            }
        });
        commentLikes = findViewById( R.id.og_likes);
        commentlikesHeart = findViewById( R.id.og_likes_heart);
        commentsRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.og_commentList);
        postKey = getIntent().getExtras().get("postKey").toString();
        postUsername = getIntent().getExtras().get("postUsername").toString();
        postTime = getIntent().getExtras().get("postTime").toString();
        postDescription = getIntent().getExtras().get("postDescription").toString();
        postProfileImage = getIntent().getExtras().get("postProfileImage").toString();
        postHasLiked = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra( "postHasLiked" );
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        postsRef = db.collection("posts" );
        commentsRef = db.collection("comments" );
        subCommentsRef = db.collection("subComments");
        dbStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        noteRef = commentsRef.document(postKey);
        setUpRecyclerView();
        commentDeleteView = findViewById(R.id.comment_delete);
        commentDeleteConfirm = findViewById(R.id.comment_delete_confirm);
        commentDeleteCancel = findViewById( R.id.comment_delete_cancel );
        commentDeleteView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        CollectionReference noteRef = db.collection( "users");
        Query query = noteRef.whereEqualTo("uid", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        query.get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                userUsername = document.getData().get("username").toString();
                                userProfileImage = document.getData().get("profileImage").toString();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
        commentPicture = findViewById(R.id.og_image);
        commentProfilePicture = findViewById(R.id.og_profileImage);
        Picasso.get().load(postProfileImage).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_action_profile).into(commentProfilePicture);
        commentUserName = findViewById(R.id.og_userName);
        commentUserName.setText(postUsername);
        commentLikes.setText("likes: " + postHasLiked.size());
        postLikes = postHasLiked.size();
        commentTime = findViewById(R.id.og_uploadTime );
        commentTime.setText(postTime);
        commentDescription = findViewById(R.id.og_description );
        commentDescription.setText(postDescription);
        commentOptionsMenu = findViewById(R.id.og_postOptions);
        commentBarFoto = findViewById(R.id.commentbar_picture);
        commentBarPost = findViewById(R.id.commentbar_post);
        postTypeString = getIntent().getExtras().get("postType").toString();
        postType = Integer.parseInt( postTypeString);

        if(postType == 0){
            commentPicture.setImageDrawable(null);
            commentPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (postType == 1){
            postPicture = getIntent().getExtras().get("postPicture").toString();
            Picasso.get().load(postPicture).into(commentPicture);
        }

        if(postHasLiked.contains(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
            commentlikesHeart.setColorFilter( Color.rgb( 255,0,0));
            isLiked = true;
        } else {
            commentlikesHeart.setColorFilter( Color.rgb( 0,0,0));
            isLiked = false;
        }

        toolbarBack.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendUserToMainActivity();
            }
        });

        commentBarPost.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(commentBarText.getText())){
                    Toast.makeText( ClickPostActivity.this, "Please type something in first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    //Alle Werte kochen
                    String ogPost = postKey;
                    String commentID = postKey + System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if(resultUri == null){
                        commentType = 0;
                    } else {
                        commentType = 1;
                    }
                    String description = commentBarText.getText().toString();
                    ArrayList<String> hasLiked = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String currentUid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    HashMap commentMap = new HashMap();
                    //alles rein
                    commentMap.put("commentID", commentID);
                    commentMap.put("commentType", commentType);
                    commentMap.put("description", description);
                    if (commentType == 0) {
                        commentMap.put("picture", null);
                    } else if (commentType == 1){
                        commentMap.put("picture", picUrl);
                    }
                    commentMap.put("hasLiked", hasLiked);
                    commentMap.put("likes", 0);
                    commentMap.put("ogPost", ogPost);
                    commentMap.put("profileImage", userProfileImage);
                    commentMap.put("time", currentTimeEdited);
                    commentMap.put("uid", currentUid);
                    commentMap.put("username", userUsername);
                    db.collection( "comments").document(commentID).set(commentMap).addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText( ClickPostActivity.this, "Comment was created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            commentBarText.setText("");
                            closeKeyboard();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        commentOptionsMenu.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                commentDeleteView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        commentDeleteCancel.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                commentDeleteView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        commentlikesHeart.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!isLiked){
                    isLiked = true;
                    postLikes++;
                    postsRef.document(postKey).update("hasLiked", FieldValue.arrayUnion(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()));
                    postsRef.document(postKey).update("likes", postLikes);
                    commentlikesHeart.setColorFilter( Color.rgb( 255,0,0));
                    commentLikes.setText("Likes: " + postLikes);
                    Toast.makeText( ClickPostActivity.this, "Comment was liked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    isLiked = false;
                    postLikes--;
                    commentlikesHeart.setColorFilter( Color.rgb( 255,255,255));
                    postsRef.document(postKey).update("hasLiked", FieldValue.arrayRemove(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()));
                    postsRef.document(postKey).update("likes", postLikes);
                    commentLikes.setText("Likes: " + postLikes);
                    Toast.makeText( ClickPostActivity.this, "Comment was disliked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        adapter.setOnConfirmCommentsClickListener( new CommentsAdapter.onConfirmCommentsClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConfirmCommentsClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                Comments comment = documentSnapshot.toObject(Comments.class);
                String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                String pic = comment.getPicture();
                if(comment.getUid().equals(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                    if(comment.getCommentType() == 1){
                        String picEdit = pic.substring(83, 124);
                        StorageReference picPlace = dbStorage.getReference();
                        StorageReference picRef = picPlace.child("postImages/"+picEdit+".jpg");
                        picRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Picture deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+e);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    adapter.deleteItem(position);
                    Toast.makeText( ClickPostActivity.this, "Post deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText( ClickPostActivity.this, "You cannot delete this post", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        adapter.setOnCommentsLikeClickListener( new CommentsAdapter.onCommentsLikeClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLikeClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                Comments comment = documentSnapshot.toObject(Comments.class);
                String id = documentSnapshot.getId();

                if(comment.getHasLiked().contains( mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Post was already liked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    db.collection( "comments" ).document(id).update("hasLiked", FieldValue.arrayRemove(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()));
                    db.collection( "comments" ).document(id).update("likes", comment.getLikes()-1);
                    Toast.makeText( ClickPostActivity.this, "Post is no longer liked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    db.collection( "comments" ).document(id).update("hasLiked", FieldValue.arrayUnion(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()));
                    db.collection( "comments" ).document(id).update("likes", comment.getLikes()+1);
                    Toast.makeText( ClickPostActivity.this, "Post was liked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        adapter.setOnSubCommentsPostClickListener( new CommentsAdapter.onSubCommentsPostClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSubCommentsPostClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position, String description) {
                Comments comment = documentSnapshot.toObject(Comments.class);
                String ogComment = documentSnapshot.getId();
                String thisdescription = description;
                ArrayList<String> hasLiked = new ArrayList<String>();
                String profileImage = userProfileImage;
                String subCommentID = ogComment + System.currentTimeMillis();
                int subCommentType = 0;
                String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                String username = userUsername;
                HashMap subCommentMap = new HashMap();
                subCommentMap.put("description", thisdescription);
                subCommentMap.put("hasLiked", hasLiked);
                subCommentMap.put("likes", 0);
                subCommentMap.put("ogComment", ogComment);
                subCommentMap.put("profileImage", profileImage);
                subCommentMap.put("subCommentID", subCommentID);
                subCommentMap.put("subCommentType", 0);
                subCommentMap.put("time", currentTimeEdited);
                subCommentMap.put("uid", uid);
                subCommentMap.put("username", userUsername);

                db.collection( "subComments").document(subCommentID).set(subCommentMap).addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText( ClickPostActivity.this, "Subcomment was created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        commentBarText.setText("");
                        closeKeyboard();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        commentBarFoto.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OpenGallery();
                Toast.makeText( ClickPostActivity.this, "Picture added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        //SubcommentsLoading

    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        Query query = commentsRef.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).whereEqualTo("ogPost", postKey);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Comments> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Comments>().setQuery(query, Comments.class).build();
        adapter = new CommentsAdapter(options);
        commentsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        commentsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager( ClickPostActivity.this));
        commentsRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
        //solange das kleine Problemchen da ist
        showKeyboard();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
```

Comment: The same "issue" again. Remember, if you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost `500` lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: man I don´t know if I cut the code part it will be almost impossible for someone to help in this case. I already cut a lot of out this time

Comment: It's always about the time for reading what you post in your question. So try to do it more concisely.